# Protocols/Framework in Class Diagram

Tags: iphone, ios, uml

In Class Diagram for iOS App. How can we show OS Class Protocols/Framework.
Suppose we have our 5 own classes and we are and some Frameworks and protocols in these classes
So how can we show them in hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this is how you can show the relationship between protocol and classes in a class diagram.

￼[image]